# "No Suitable Driver Found..." SQLite JDBC jar

Tags: sqlite, jdbc

I am trying to create a small proof-of-concept program with JDBC. I was able to get it working on one of my machines (an older Mac with an x86 processor), but when I moved it to a newer laptop (Macbook with an M1 processor, if that matter) to continue development. It no longer works:

[image]

I know I have the jar added to the build path in Eclipse:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you also have the `slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar` on the classpath, it is required since version 3.43.2.0.